# MongoDB match document where embeded document (array of objects) has (nested) array field occuring value only once

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following *schema* in my database:

```
{
   _id: Number,
   reagents: [ //Array of objects (embedded) FIND IF certain tag in v_class occurred only once in array
       {
           _id: Number,
           v_class: Array, //A single array (string only): ['TEST','PREMIUM']
       },
       {
           _id: Number,
           v_class: Array, //A single array (string only): ['TEST','PREMIUM']
       },
       {
           _id: Number,
           v_class: Array, //A single array (string only): ['TEST','PREMIUM']
       }
   ],
   other_fields: other_values,
}
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iVgndfgbie9)

The question is all about:

> How to find only that documents, where `reagents` field have only one item (reagent, embedded documents), among `v_class` array field consist the word `PREMIUM`.

So from the selected collection above, I want to have only document with `_id: 2` because it's the only document where `reagents` field have **THE ONLY** document, where in field called `v_class` word `PREMIUM` occurring only once.

**UPD**: I have achieved a bit simple results after `$group` stage, [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qfJpHhrzhDw) (after group). So as for now, I still need to find docs where `v_class` array field occurring `PREMIUM` value exactly once in it's array`

**UPD2:** I have new version has appeared. [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JUbR15wod-E). This query is fine, but it shows all the `PREMIUM` except that occurred just once.

Comment: In your example, there is no document with a sigle `PREMIUM` in the `v_class` array of `reagents`.

Comment: Or do you want to find documents that have "premium" occurring exactly once in any of the v_classes (not is the only element of a v_class)?

Comment: @MickaelB. single doesn't mean that `v_class` array field will have only `["PREMIUM"]` value, it means that I need to find only one doc, with `v_class` = consist `PREMIUM` so it could be like `['X', 'PREMIUM']

Comment: @Oleg, y you right, thank you so much for pointing me out, I will correct the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$sum` needs a numeric value to make sense.

Once you have the sum, an additional `$match` stage can compare the sum to 1.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/TKQowD-vd0f

Comment: I just found it: https://mongoplayground.net/p/JWWy8LPgk5j So the key question for now, how can I return the original doc by `_id` cause  `recipe_id` field represents it in my case?

Comment: I imagine performing another $lookup to join the original collection to the existing results will achieve that.

Comment: `$out` ? (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: There is no question there, actually you are right about `$lookup` stage cause at first I think that `$out` could return the original doc from the collection, but instead it creates a new collection of documents with a specific name.

Answer (score 1):

I have found my own way to find the result, separately from Oleg, but he was first, so I upvote him and accept as answer his variant.

My query has the only one difference. It returns the original documents itself, not just reference fields.

Full query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      reagents: {
        $elemMatch: {
          _id: 12
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        v_class: "$reagents.v_class",
        recipe_id: "$_id"
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$_id.v_class"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "_id.v_class": "PREMIUM"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.recipe_id",
      count: {
        $sum: 1,

      },
      data: {
        "$first": "$data"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      count: 1
    }
  }
])
```

It finds the exact item in reagents (`Array`) field by ID, and it's document has a `v_class` (`Array`) field check if it's value/tag occurred only once.

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ALPlDMk9B-L)